# limitar o for, php

Tags: php, desempenho, paginação, get

Bom é o seguinte, eu estou gerando links de paginação para obter mais leveza em meu sistema, o problema é tenho muitos registros no banco de dados e essa paginação gera muitos links, assim ocupando uma parte bem grande da pagina, gostaria de saber se é possível limitar o for no php para que ele gere os links dinamicamente não ocupando muito espaço em pagina, ou se existe uma forma mais inteligente de como melhorar meu código, obrigado

[image: veja como está sendo gerado]

o código que utilizo atualmente é este

$qtdPag = recebe o valor de total de registros dividido por resultados por pagina

$pg = recebe via GET a pagina atual

```
 if($qtdPag > 1 && $pg <= $qtdPag){   

            for($i = 1; $i <= $qtdPag; $i++){
                    if($i == $pg){
                            echo "<i>[".$i."]</i>";
                    } else {
                            echo "<i><a href='socios.php?pg=$i'>[".$i."]</a></i>";
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Voce tambem poder dar um `LIMIT` na consulta que vem do banco, isso limitaria a quantidade de registros que vem do bancom e consequentemente a paginação

Comment: o grande problema é o fato de usar sql server, ele não aceita o limit (alias isso vem me trazendo grandes problemas)

Comment: Alias... porque não trabalha com o JPaginate?

Comment: bom eu sou 'novato' digamos assim, não quero usar ferramentas que facilitem o caminho antes de realmente aprender a logica geral

Comment: Olha... em relação ao SQL Server, ve se esse link te ajuda: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Se o SQL Server tiver `LIMIT` resolve seu problema? Viu que tem o `TOP`?

Comment: Sim, ta no link que eu enviei o `TOP` @bigow, em relação a limitar a quantidade de links, voce teria que trazer todas os registros, continuaria aparecendo todos os links de página, o que você faria seria um tratamento via JS e/ou via CSS

Comment: pois é vou ter que dar um jeito com JS mesmo, o problema é que eu realmente sou horrível, péssimo, com javascript, não entendo a logica em geral e sempre ando evitando, mas vou tentar a sua solução marcelo, do JPaginate..

Comment: Vou tentar te dar um auxilio mano, perai

Comment: tudo bem marcelo, obg pelo auxilio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma:

```
$qtdPag = 20;
$pg = 10;

$dottedBefore = false;
$dottedAfter = false;

if ($qtdPag > 1 && $pg <= $qtdPag) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $qtdPag; $i++) {
        if ($i == $pg) {
            echo "<i>[" . $i . "]</i>";
        } else if ($i < ($pg - 5) && $i != 1) {
            if (!$dottedBefore) {
                echo "<i>[...]</i>";
                $dottedBefore = true;
            }
        } else if ($i > ($pg + 5) && $i < $qtdPag) {
            if (!$dottedAfter) {
                echo "<i>[...]</i>";
                $dottedAfter = true;
            }
        } else {
            echo "<i><a href='socios.php?pg=" . $i . "'>[" . $i . "]</a></i>";
        }
    }
}
```

O que este script faz é limitar o número de páginas exibidas antes e depois da página atual, colocando `[...]` nestes espaços. As variáveis `$dottedBefore` e `$dottedAfter` são utilizadas para verificar se já foi exibida a string `[...]`.

Caso queira alterar o número de páginas exibidas antes ou depois da página atual, basta alterar o número da condição correspondente.

Se o código ficou confuso deixe um comentário, mas acredito que dando uma boa analisada você vai entender sem problemas. =)

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução sem usar o `JPaginate`:

HTML:

```
< body onload="mostraDez()">
< input type="button" onclick="primeiro()" value="<<"/>
< input type="button" onclick="primeiro()" value="<<"/>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<input type='hidden' id='pgAtual' value='".$_GET['pg']."'/>";
$qtdPag = 322; //Aqui a quantidade total de páginas

if($qtdPag > 1 && $_GET['pg'] <= $qtdPag){   
    for($i = 1; $i <= $qtdPag; $i++){
        if($i == $_GET['pg']){
            echo "<i>[".$i."]</i>";
        }else{
            echo "<i><a id='".$i."' href='teste.php?pg=".$i."' style='display:none'>[".$i."]</a></i>";
        }
    }

    echo "<input type='hidden' id='qtdEle' value='".$i."'/>";
}
```

`insira o código aqui`?>

JS:

```
function mostraDez(){
    atual = document.getElementById("pgAtual").value;
    for (var i = (parseInt(atual)+5); atual < i; i--) {
        if (i >= 1){
            document.getElementById(i).style.display = "inline";
            console.log(i);
        }
    }

    for (var i = (parseInt(atual)-5); atual > i; i++) {
        if (i >= 1){
            document.getElementById(i).style.display = "inline";
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}

function primeiro(){
    location.href = "teste.php?pg=1";
}

function ultimo(){
    location.href = "teste.php?pg=" + document.getElementById("qtdEle").value;
}
```

Seria necessário ainda algumas manipulações da lógica pra quando ele estiver em valores do tipo 1, 2, 3 e/ou 320, 321, 322 ele continuar mostrando dez, em vez de somente 5... se quiser eu implemento aqui